# pipenv and wheel/pre-compiled packages

Tags: python, pip, python-wheel, pipenv

I'm currently using a buildhost for third party packages running

`$ pip3 wheel --wheel-dir=/root/wheelhouse -r /requirements.txt`

After successful build I copy the directory `/root/wheelhouse` onto a new machine and install the compiled packages by running

`$ pip3 install -r /requirements.txt --no-index --find-links=/root/wheelhouse`

Is there something similar in `pipenv`?
Everything I found in combination with `wheel` are bug reports on GitHub.

Note that copying the venv directory is not an option. I'm using a docker container and want to install the packages system wide.

Comment: I have the same question. It seems that using file:// in source url doesn't do the trick... Is there a way to use pipenv with local source repository?